Error while creating connection in Oracle SQL Developer extension in VS code
Trying to add a connection

It gives this error:
Error: An error occurred when attempting to connect to the database.The following error occurred: ORA-12541: Cannot connect. No listener at host localhost port 1521. (CONNECTION_ID=Xi6YwC6qTneWJpnBNDbovA==)
https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-12541/. Consult your database documentation for information on how to resolve the specified error code

I am new to Oracle-SQL-developer and was trying to use VS-code Extension. Can you tell me steps to fix this?

did you actually install a really old copy of Oracle Database as well? 'XE' is a name of a database you created, probably something like 11gR2 Express edition. The VS Code extension doesn't come with an Oracle Database.

No Even when I change Service name, It gives same error

tell us which database you installed and created?

I have just installed the extension for Oracle through VS code, nothing else. I was needed connection to continue

Ok, so you need a database, too. Some resources here for you. https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/02/im-a-student-studying-oracle-and-i-need-a-database-help/
